# Lehman Brothers (is/are) now taken over by some other company

Tags: verb-agreement

> Lehman Brothers (**is/are**) now taken over by some other company.

My answer is *is*.

My approach to finding the correct answer is that according to subject–verb agreement rules, if both of them refer to same subject, we use a singular verb. Thus:

> Lehman Brothers is now taken over by some other company.

Is my approach right according to subject–verb agreement rules?

Comment: This is a US/UK thing.

Comment: There is a variance in usage here between AmE and BrE speakers. AmE speakers universally conceive of corporate bodies and unified, whole, and therefor singular. By contrast, in many, but not all cases, BrE speakers envision such bodies as groups of individuals, plural. So there is no single, correct, answer to your question. As an American, I'd say *is*: *the company is being taken over*. But a British person might say *are*: *the employees and people of Lehman Brothers are being acquired*. YMMV.

Comment: It's not clear from the question what "if both of them refer to the same subject" means. However, the linked question and the trail of duplicates linked there will be helpful in dealing with company names.